# How to define/declare xaml namespace in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

The other day i was searching for DataProviders in XAML and i found this article [Bind to methods with ObjectDataProvider](http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2008/01/10/bind-to-methods-with-objectdataprovider/), which explains about ObjectDataProvider. So i thought to give it a try. So when i copy-paste xaml and code behind file, i got invalid markup error due to namespace mismatch in my xaml file. I solved it by trial and error but i did not got the full concept of XAML and its name spaces, So i would like to know more in detail.

Comment: Read up [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: ppl goto msdn for such things :)

Comment: @Muds Already been there at MSDN. MSDN is not new comer friendly.

Comment: @ByomkeshBakhsy: It is. It explains it all.

Comment: in that caase so is worse :P

Comment: When someone asks a question on here that yes, does have a lot of links in Google about it, what they are really asking is for someone to answer the question with plain language and to put it in context, such as why do we need it, who will use it most, do we need to know it to build WPF apps in Visual Studio, etc. Because most often the links you find about it on Google are in "tech-speak" and for a beginner this is confusing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML relies on the namespace-concepts of the .Net Framework. You just can make use of Components, which are located in another namespace (in your example it's the ColorHelper). But you have to tell the the XAML-Compiler (yes XAML can get compiled), where to find the stuff you're trying to use. You are doing this by first declaring a xml namespace:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SimpleObjectDataProvider"
```

Then on the other line

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="colors"
    ObjectType="{x:Type local:ColorHelper}"
    MethodName="GetColorNames"/>
```

you can use all the classes/WPF-Controls that are defined in this namespace.
The example on the link you posted may be a bit confusing, because there is not showed where (in which namespace) the class ColorHelper is defined.